# rdl report builder file not launching from SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint, reportbuilder

I have links to 2 SharePoint sites (different servers) and when I click on the menu option "Edit in Report Builder" on one site it does not load as supposed to the other. I get a dialog that has a show details button on it which when clicked opens a log file. The log file says:

```
...
Activation of <path>\ReportBuilder_3_0_0_0.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
  System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
    + Downloading file:///<path>/RptBuilder_3/MSReportBuilder.exe.manifest did not succeed.
...
```

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

All I know is that I designed the ones on the site that works using Report Builder 12.0. If I go by the error above does this mean report builder 3.0 and so not backward compatible?

I have also tried the clear cache option but that does not work for me either, i.e.:

```
Open command window
Type: cd C:\Windows\System32
Type: rundll32 dfshim CleanOnlineAppCache
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems their is an issue between servers that I cannot put my finger on. This is not the ideal solution but simply a workaround.

```
Goto the following folder C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0
Delete all contents (this is the cached files)
Reopen report
```

The problem with this temporary solution is works for one server only so I have to repeat each time to switch between the 2 - very annoying.

If someone has a more permanent solution please let me know.